Graalvm Springboot with log4j2
I am building a native image using Graalvm(GraalVM 17.0.11+7.1) for a Springboot(3.1.11) Microservice which has log4j2 dependency. While running the image getting following error.
Any suggestion to get this resolved?
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:61)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:146)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:113)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:194)
        at vf.vbps.dxl.tmfusageconsumptionmanagement.trendmicro.Application.main(Application.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.DefaultFlowMessageFactory
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.createDefaultFlowMessageFactory(AbstractLogger.java:242)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.<init>(AbstractLogger.java:141)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<init>(StatusLogger.java:141)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:91)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.DefaultFlowMessageFactory
        at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.Class.newInstance(DynamicHub.java:639)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.createDefaultFlowMessageFactory(AbstractLogger.java:240)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.DefaultFlowMessageFactory.<init>()
        at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.Class.checkMethod(DynamicHub.java:1042)
        at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(DynamicHub.java:1208)
        at java.base@17.0.11/java.lang.Class.newInstance(DynamicHub.java:626)
        ... 12 more```


can you share your pom xml ?
